# js exported variable is not updating unless file that imports it being saved again

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to use `import/export` in js files but it's working strange.

```
// file_A.js
var test = "hello";
export {test};
```

```
// file_B.js
import {test} from "./file_A";
console.log(test);
```

-

It prints "hello" like I expected.
Everything works fine, until I change the value in file_A.js.
If I change file_A.js like below and save it,

```
// file_A.js
var test = "bye";
export {test};
```

browser automatically reloads, but it prints "hello", which has not updated my changes in the file_A.js.

But if I save file_B.js again, despite that I haven't changed anything in file_B.js, suddenly the value is updated and prints "bye".

So every time I change the exported variable in file_A.js, I have to save file_B.js as well. This is very annoying.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

I use Cuttlebelle - react framework, and I use Codekit with Babel, UMD bundle format.